# Sed print only lines with at least 2 words

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

Hi I'm Trying to write code only with simple sed commands.
Here is my question:

I want to print certain lines from a file, these are the conditions:

-Only if the line has at least 2 words

-Only if the second Word has at least 3 characters

-After the above conditions are followed the lines must be printed regularly except for the second word in the line which its first 3 characters must be doubled.
**EDIT:**

**This Part Can Be Done In AWK**

-In the last Line it must print the amount of lines from the original file which weren't included

Example:

```
abc2 1 def2 3 abc2
dea 123 123 zy45
12 12
abc cd abc cd
xyz%$@! x@yz%$@! kk
xyzxyz
abc htzw
```

Output:

```
dea 112233 123 zy45
xyz%$@! xx@@yyz%$@! kk
abc hhttzzw
4
```

This is My current code:

```
sed -r '/[ ]*([^ ]+[ ]){2,}/!d' ex >| tmp
sed -r '/[ ]*[^ ]+[ ][^ ]{3,}/!d' tmp >| tmp2
sed -r 's/([ ]*[^ }+[ ])([^ ])([^ ])([^ ])(*)/\1 \2 \2 \3 \3 \4 \4 \5/' tmp2 
>| tmp
```

But I seem to be getting an error which I can't fix and I can't figure out how I would print the number 4 ( See example ).

The error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 62: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Any Help would be great :)

Comment: Your example contains no single 4. Where does the single "4" come from?

Comment: At the beginning there were 7 lines but in the output there were only 3, 7-3. The 4 symbolizes the amount of lines that were in the beginning and weren't in the output @Cyrus

Comment: Do you need to use `sed` for this? It would be much easier with `awk`.

Comment: yes I need to write it in sed @PesaThe

Comment: You have to count something, and you can only use sed? While not impossible, it's a giant hassle. Have a look at [counting in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#wc-_002dc) for an idea.

Comment: question has been edited @BenjaminW.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? I'd have a few choice words for the instructor if so ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r '/^[ ]*[^ ]+[ ][^ ]+([ ]|$)/!d' ex >| tmp
sed -r '/^[ ]*[^ ]+[ ][^ ]+([ ]|$)/d' ex >| delete
sed -r '/^[ ]*[^ ]+[ ][^ ]{3,}/d' tmp >> delete
sed -r '/^[ ]*[^ ]+[ ][^ ]{3,}/!d' tmp >| yolo
sed -r 's/(^[ ]*[^ ]+[ ])([^ ])([^ ])([^ ])(.*)/\1\2\2\3\3\4\4\5/' yolo
sed -n '$=' delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (sed + bash)

```
nb=$(sed -n '$=' infile)
sed -E '
  /([^ ]* )([^[:space:]]*)(.*)/h
  s//\2/
  tA
  d
  :A
  s/([^[:space:]])([^[:space:]])([^[:space:]])(.*)/\1\1\2\2\3\3\4/
  tB
  d
  :B
  G
  s/(.*)\n([^ ]* )([^[:space:]]*)(.*)/\2\1\4/
' infile > infilebis
cat infilebis
echo $(($nb - $(sed -n '$=' infilebis)))
rm infilebis
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your task can be done with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -rn 's/^([^ ]+ )([^ ])([^ ])([^ ])/\1\2\2\3\3\4\4/; T; p' input.txt
```

> **T label** -
>                 If  no  s/// has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since
>                 the last t or T command, then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
>                 This is a GNU extension.

**Output**

```
dea 112233 123 zy45
xyz%$@! xx@@yyz%$@! kk
abc hhttzzw
```

#### Version with the number of not included lines

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -rn '
    s/^([^ ]+ )([^ ])([^ ])([^ ])/\1\2\2\3\3\4\4/
    T branch
    p; d
    :branch
    w not_included.txt
' input.txt

wc -l < not_included.txt
```

**Output**

```
dea 112233 123 zy45
xyz%$@! xx@@yyz%$@! kk
abc hhttzzw
4
```